# How to use Request->all() with Eloquent models

Tags: json, laravel, model, request, lumen

I have a lumen application where I need to store incoming JSON Request. If I write a code like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    if ($request->isJson())
    {
      $data = $request->all();

      $transaction = new Transaction();
      if (array_key_exists('amount', $data))
        $transaction->amount = $data['amount'];
      if (array_key_exists('typology', $data))
        $transaction->typology = $data['typology'];

      $result = $transaction->isValid();
      if($result === TRUE )
      {
        $transaction->save();
        return $this->response->created();
      }

      return $this->response->errorBadRequest($result);
    }

    return $this->response->errorBadRequest();
  }
```

It works perfectly. But use Request in that mode is boring because I have to check every input field to insert them to my model. Is there a fast way to send request to model?

Answer (score 24):

You can do mass assignment to Eloquent models, but you need to first set the fields on your model that you want to allow to be mass assignable. In your model, set your `$fillable` array:

```
class Transaction extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['amount', 'typology'];
}
```

This will allow the `amount` and `typology` to be mass assignable. What this means is that you can assign them through the methods that accept arrays (such as the constructor, or the `fill()` method).

An example using the constructor:

```
$data = $request->all();
$transaction = new Transaction($data);

$result = $transaction->isValid();
```

An example using `fill()`:

```
$data = $request->all();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->fill($data);

$result = $transaction->isValid();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can either use `fill` method or the `constructor`. First you must include all mass assignable properties in `fillable` property of your model

Method 1 (Use constructor)

```
$transaction = new Transaction($request->all());
```

Method 2 (Use `fill` method)

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->fill($request->all());
```

Comment: @patricus answer is more complete as it contains `isValid()` call which the code of the questioner contains. And it stops me from using `$fooModel->some_foo_col = $request->get('some_foo_col ');` ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your TransactionRequest with rules extends FormRequest
2. 

> ```
>   public function store(TransactionRequest $request)
>   {
>
>       $transaction = new Transaction($request->validated());
>
>       $transaction->save();
>   }
> ```