# Laravel 5.3 Update method not working

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-5.3

i'm working on an API i have a resource controller to CRUD the drivers, in my update functon i'm getting this error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'registration_center' cannot be null (SQL: update `drivers` set `registration_center` = , `registration_date` = 04-02-2017, `sponsor_name` = , `event_name` = , `registration_id` = 040217001, `profile_photo` = , `first_name` = , `last_name` = ,`updated_at` = 2017-02-04 04:54:54 where `id` = 3)
```

i did `dd($request);` in my update method i got all the JSON response

```
Request {#40
  #json: ParameterBag {#32
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "data" => array:61 [
        "id" => 3
        "agent_id" => "201705"
        "registration_center" => "dfgsdfgdfgdsdfgdf"
        "registration_date" => "03-02-2017"
        "sponsor_name" => "Sponser Name"
        "event_name" => "RC"
        "registration_id" => "FRTGHY030217001"
        "profile_photo" => ""","
        "first_name" => "Walter"
        "last_name" => "White"
        "created_at" => "2017-01-24 10:08:42"
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-03 11:33:52"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
    ]
  }
```

but for `dd($request->registration_center);`  i'm getting `NULL`

My Method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $update_driver = Driver::find($id);

    $update_driver->registration_center = $request->registration_center;
    $update_driver->registration_date = $request->registration_date;
    $update_driver->sponsor_name = $request->sponsor_name;
    $update_driver->event_name = $request->event_name;
    $update_driver->registration_id = $request->registration_id;
    $update_driver->profile_photo = $request->profile_photo;
    $update_driver->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $update_driver->last_name = $request->last_name;                        
    $update_driver->save();

    return $this->respondUpdated('Driver updated successfully');
}
```

My Routes are

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('user', 'UsersController@index');
    Route::resource('drivers', 'DriversController'); //drivers CRUD
});
```

Looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: decode your json data.

Comment: Search the php function of `json_decode`

Comment: How you are calling `update` method and also share what you get in `json_decode($request)` ?

Comment: @Rishi i'm using postman PUT request to test the api, i got `NULL` when i `$request = json_decode($req);
     dd($request);`

Comment: @MrRobot what does `dd($request->all());` show?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i'm getting `array:1 [
  "data" => array:61 [
    "id" => 3
    "agent_id" => "201702"
    "registration_center" => "dfgfsdgdfgdfgfd"
    "registration_date" => "03-02-2017"
    "sponsor_name" => "Sponser Name"
    "event_name" => "Transport Mithra"
    "registration_id" => "FRTGHY030217001"
    "profile_photo" => ""","
    "first_name" => "Walter"
    "last_name" => "White"
  ]
]`  i'm getting all the form values from the POSTman

Comment: @MrRobot could you please add the dump of `$request->all()` to your question above? It would make it easier to answer and the formatting would be better too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to access POSTed data from a Laravel request is to use the `input` method.

```
$field = $request->input('field');
```

Looking at your example, it seems like the `Request` object has a `data` field in it which is an associative array and the `registration_center` is inside that. If I got that right, then in your case, you would use:

```
$update_driver->registration_center = $request->input('data')['registration_center'];

// or, using Laravel's "dot"-syntax
$update_driver->registration_center = $request->input('data.registration_center');
```

to access the data. Similarly for all the other values you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: thank you for your time i did  `dd($request->input('data.registration_center'));` in POSTman i'm getting response `NULL` but if i do `dd($request->all());` i'm getting all the values

Comment: Okay, let's try to debug this. What do you get when you do `dd($request->input('data'));` ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time really appreciate it, now i'm not storing the data in associative array i'm just sending an JSON object, things are working fine, thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: can you please tell me how do i display error if the value did not updated for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an array, you need to access it with:

```
$request['data']['registration_center'];
```

Comment: thank you, how do i mass update the values insted as i'm doing now

Comment: For mass assignment, you might want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35631336/2141058